# Controller @Mixin just works after recompile of running app

Tags: grails, groovy, mixins

Within my latest grails 2.3.0 project I'm using the `@Mixin` annotation to mixin a helper class to keep my `controller` more DRY.

The mixin is just working if a made some changes within the controller to force a recompile of the controller. After the initial compile (`grails run-app`) the helper isn't mixed in - I get a `MissingMethodException` trying to access a method from the helper class.

Here is my helper witin `src/groovy`:

```
class ProjectHelper {
    def withProject(id, Closure c) {
        def project = Project.get(id)
        if (project) {
            c.call project
        } else {
            flash.message = 'Project not found!'
            render view: 'myView'
            return
        }
    }
}
```

And (one of) the `controller` which uses the `ProjectHelper`:

```
@Mixin(ProjectHelper)
class ProjectController {
    def index() {
        withProject params.projectId, {project ->
            // do something with the project
        }
    }
}
```

When I cleane the project using `grails clean` and starting the app, I get the following error after accessing `project/index`:

```
MissingMethodException occurred when processing request: 
    [GET] /<myApp>/project/
    No signature of method: <myPackage>.withProject() is applicable for argument types: 
    (java.lang.String, <myPackage>.ProjectController$_index_closure1_closure10) values: 
    [1, <myPackage>.ProjectController$_index_closure1_closure10@40d889b5]
```

After some changes in `ReportController` (e.g. adding a single space) grails compiles 2 source files and the method `withProject` could be used. Accessing `project/index` works as expected.

What's going wrong here? Is it a bug or do I miss something?

**Update**

It turns out that I totally missed, that using the `grails.util.Mixin` gives me another exception (`MissingPropertyException`) due to missing access to the mixed in class properties (in my case: `flash`) (see [JIRA this issue](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9905)) which is working with `groovy.lang.Mixin` (after recompile).

Is there a way to manually recompile/inject/mixin the `groovy.lang.Mixin` at runtime or do I have to find another error handling for the `else` part till the issue is fixed?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which @Mixin? `groovy.lang.Mixin` or `grails.util.Mixin`? Try to use the other if it is a groovy mixin.

Comment: I tried both. Neither the one nor the other worked.

Comment: @dmahapatro I checked it again! It was a little late yesterday - I missed that grails.util.Mixin gives another Exception. I will update my question ...

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue! I'm trying to DRY up my controllers in the same way even! It would be great if we could do exactly what we are trying, but it doesn't look like the method is getting added to the controller at all. (recompile doesn't fix it for me). Do you know if there is a Jira ticket for this bug yet?

Comment: @cdeszaq Yes! There is already an jira issue: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9905

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had been regularly running into the same `MissingMethodException` when following a similar code reuse pattern using mixins.

In my case, changing `groovy.lang.Mixin` to `grails.util.Mixin` (or more specifically, adding an import for `grails.util.Mixin` to my controller) resolved the issue completely.

As for not having access to the controller variables, you may be stuck waiting for [GRAILS-9905](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9905) to be resolved.  I should note that there are some suggested work-arounds listed on the defect discussion, though.

Comment: No idea why but this doesn't work. I tried both `@Mixin` annotation with import and without :/

Answer (score 1):

The workaround that finally worked for me was to manually injecting the `Mixin` in the Controller constructor:

```
import com.example.MyMixin

class SomethingController {
  def SomethingController() {
    SomethingController.metaClass.mixin(MyMixin)
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this also doesn't work with grails v. 2.3.7 or maybe I'm missing something. Really annoying.

Comment: @Opal I'm stuck using 2.2.4. Not sure, but perhaps you can do `SomethingController.mixin MyMixin` directly (without the `metaClass`). You basically want a [runtime mixin](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Runtime+mixins).

Comment: @grammar31 Worked for me, I use Grails 2.3.11. Thank you for this answer.