# Exception handling with dynamic mixins in Grails controller

Tags: grails, mixins

I am using dynamic mixins on my Grails 2.3.11 controllers [according to this proposal on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22817283), for DRY reasons:

```
class SomeApiController {
    def SomeApiController() {
        SomeApiController.mixin MyControllerMixin
    }
    ...
```

Unfortunately it does not work for exception handlers, like:

```
class MyControllerMixin {
    ...
    def businessException( BusinessException e ) {
        log.error( "API exception: ${e.message} ${e.errorCode}", e )
        def result = [
            status: 'Failure',
            errorCode: e.errorCode.name()
        ]
        response.status = 400
        render result as JSON
    }
    ...
}
```

In this case, the default exception handler in `SomeApiController` is called when a `BusinessException` is thrown from somewhere. It works nicely if I place the handler directly in the controller, though, but this is what I want to avoid obviously.

Is there any workaround to get that working as well?

Comment: Probably because your mixin change is done at runtime, and handling exceptions is done at compilation time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#controllerExceptionHandling.  That includes the following...

> Exception handler methods must be present at compile time.
>   Specifically, exception handler methods which are runtime
>   metaprogrammed onto a controller class are not supported.

Comment: I know that you are using 2.3.11 so this won't help you right now but be aware that when/if you move to 2.4 you can use a trait for this.  See https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11453.  I implemented that for 2.4.1.

Comment: One approach you might use for 2.3.11 is to define the exception handler methods in a base class that your controllers extend.  That isn't as slick as using a trait, but you can't use traits in 2.3.11.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I missed that part in the docs! Will go for traits eventually but for now I'm stuck with 2.3.x.